# I can't run this code to print distance between two points. I am just a beginner

Tags: c++, constructor

I wrote the code given below to print distance between two points but it throws a lot of errors. As much as I know, the errors lie in "void formula(distance o1, distance o2)"and main. But I couldn't find exact errors as I am just a beginner. Please guide me.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

class distance
{
     int a, b;
public:
    int c, d;

    friend void formula(distance, distance);

    distance(int a1, int b1)
    {
        a = a1;
        b = b1;
    }
 };

void formula(distance o1, distance o2)
{
    c = o2.a - o1.a;
    d = o2.b - o1.b;
    cout<<"The distance is "<<sqrt((c*c)+(d*d))<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    distance c1(1, 2), c2(3, 4);
    formula(c1, c2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what are the errors? You should read them. If you do not understand them you should include them in the question so others can expain

Comment: Some typographic errors. E.g. `sqrt((c*c)+(d*d)`. Just work through them. Sometimes the compiler doesn't realise immediately and blames a later part of the code. What are `c` and `d` too?  Looks like you might need to go back a few steps. Read Stroustrup!

Comment: And a suggestion: Your class should probably only have 2 member variables. Subtract `c1`  from `c2` to get a third instance (`distance result = c1 - c2;`). Pythagoras on `result`'s members will be the distance between `c1` and `c2`. Also, `distance` is not a good name. You say it yourself in the title.: "point"

Comment: maybe thats your misunderstanding: A `friend` is not a member function. You are not using the member `c` and `d` anywhere and `c` and `d` in `formula` are different (not declared) integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I compiled your code using g++, and here are some of the errors I found:

### Spelling

`#inclulde <math.h>`

### Friend Function

you defined `formula` outside of class `distance`, but declared it as a friend function inside. The easiest way to fix this is to just define formula where you declared it, ie inside the class.

```
class distance
{
    ...
    friend void formula(distance o1, distance o2)
    { /* code */ }
    ...
};
```

### Variable declaration/assignment

```
void formula(distance o1, distance o2)
{
    c = o2.a - o1.a;
    d = o2.b - o1.b;
    cout<<"The distance is "<<sqrt((c*c)+(d*d))<<endl;
}
```

what type are c and d? you might know, but the compiler certainly doesn't. you need to declare them before you assign them:

```
int c;
c = o2.a - o1.a;
// or
int c = o2.a - o1.a;
```

### Constructing objects

```
int main()
{
    distance(c1(1, 2), c2(3, 4));
    formula(c1, c2);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't really know what you are trying to do here, its hard to interpret. I am guessing you are trying to create two distance objects, c1 and c2, and then use them as parameters for formula.

to construct an instance of an object, you can do one of the following:

```
distance c1(1,2);
distance c1 = distance(1,2);
distance c1 = {1, 2};
distance c1{1,2};
```

these all do essentially the same thing.

### Final Notes

avoid `using namespace std`, it causes problems such as ambiguous reference errors (caused by the a naming clash with your distance class and something the std namespce)

following is a version of your code that will compile, though I don't know if it does what you want it to do.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>

class Distance
{
     int a, b;
public:

    friend void formula(Distance o1, Distance o2)
    {
        int c = o2.a - o1.a;
        int d = o2.b - o1.b;
        std::cout<<"The distance is "<<std::sqrt((c*c)+(d*d))<<std::endl;
    }

    Distance(int a1, int b1)
    {
        a = a1;
        b = b1;
    }
 };


int main()
{
    Distance c1(1,2);
    Distance c2 = {1,2};
    Distance c3{1,2};
    Distance c4 = Distance(1,2);
    formula(c1, c2);
    return 0;
}
```